# Different page if text after URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Here's what I'd like to do: If someone goes to my domain (i.e. `url.com`), they're taken to index.html, as usual. But, if they go to `url.com/helloworld`, they're taken to profile.php, with a POST value of whatever they typed after the slash, while keeping the URL in the URL bar at `url.com/helloworld`. Is there a way to do this with htaccess, or some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root (where `http://url.com/` would normally resolve to):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /profile.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

This assumes that the `helloworld` part doesn't point to an existing file or directory and it doesn't contain any slashes. So `hello/world` won't work and `index.html` won't work (assuming you have a file there called `index.html`.

If you need slashes to work, you can change the `^([^/]+)$` above to `^(.+)$` so that it captures *everything* after the hostname.

Comment: Worked perfectly, changed it to `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /profile.php?n=$1 [L,QSA]` for this scenario.